# gnome-disk-utility or hdparm to spin down hdd permanently → issues

Tags: kde, gnome-disk-utility, spindown, hdparm

I used to use this `hdparm -Y /dev/sda` under KDE to spin down hdd disk but this stopped to work as disk started to spin up by itself, I couldn't find a way to correct this by using other hdparm parameters and afrer a wide research found that still this function offers `gnome-disk-utility` and work like a charm but...I would like to make disk spun down at startup and found that this gnome-disks app offers really only few options via terminal, it's rather GUI app...anyway if somebody know how this may be done and hdd disk spun down at each system startup I would appreciate this help

Comment: You haven't provided any OS/release details. This may matter as it gives a clue as to your GTK+ stack & thus versions of software (like `gnome-disk-utility`), let alone your Qt/KDE stack.